# Global Import In ES6

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I have a large third party library that I need to share between two projects. The project has multiple folders with multiple files that contain multiple exports. Instead of importing these modules like this

```
import {BaseContainer} from '@company/customproject/src/containers/BaseContainer.js'
```

I would like to do this

```
import { BaseContainer } from '@company/customproject'
```

I know I can manually import all the modules into a single index.js file in the base directory but i am wondering if there is an easier way to do not have import them all explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I can manually import all the modules into a single index.js file in the base directory but i am wondering if there is an easier way to do not have import them all explicitly

You should really just create an `index.js` file and import into that whatever you want to export so that you can control what APIs get exported and to not export private APIs.

That said there is an [automated tool](https://github.com/gajus/create-index) that generates an `index.js` automatically for you:

```
> npm install -g create-index
> create-index ./src
```

Which will generate an `index.js` with all the exports.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggests, you should create an `index.js` within each directory and explicitly export contents

**@company/customproject/index.js**

```
import {BaseContainer, SomeOtherContainer} from './src/containers'

export {
  BaseContainer,
  SomeOtherContainer
}
```

**@company/customproject/src/containers/index.js**

```
import BaseContainer from './BaseContainer'
import SomeOtherContainer from './SomeOtherContainer'

export {
  BaseContainer,
  SomeOtherContainer
}
```

Another option to autoload an entire directory is using `require` and `module.exports` to export every scanned file, however. You would likely run into conflicts using both ES6 import/export along with `module.exports` and default export statements.

**@company/customproject/index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const modules = {}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/src/containers').forEach(file => {
  file = file.replace('.js', '')
  modules[file] = require('./src/containers/'+file)
  // map default export statement
  if (modules[file].default) {
    modules[file] = modules[file].default
  }
})

module.exports = modules
```

Then simply use it in any ES5 or ES6 module

```
const {BaseContainer} = require('@company/customproject')
```

or

```
import {BaseContainer} from '@company/customproject'
```